# C# override ToString so that it displays multi-line stuff text in debugger

Tags: c#, debugging, tostring, multiline

How do I override and format string in `ToString` method to get multiline debug message, when I mouse over some variable in debuger. Currently when I return multiline string (seperated by `\r\n`), it still ends up in single line in debugger.

Comment: could you try passing Environment.NewLine..? wait a minute you can't do this in the debugger.. however you could just write out to the Console.. that's would I would suggest doing.. override ToString() is generally used if you want to override the .ToString() method with your own string of formatted string.. otherwise I would just write to the Console or like @Slaks has suggested print to the immediate window

Comment: That's not really what ToString is for. If I wanted a way to ask an object for a "Debug String" I'd add a new interface something like `IDebugString` with a "ToDebugString" method and call that.

Comment: If you adopt asawyer's approach, make sure that you use the [`DebuggerDisplay` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx) to instruct the debugger to use that particular method!

Comment: What I am looking for is something similar to how you see List items as strings on seperate rows. Our product is building source trees and they often get really complicated and long, so clicking on magnifying glass icon is no-good, since it closes currently open variable tree (a.b.c[12].d)

Comment: Then you're looking for a debugger visualizer, as Christian's answer suggests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could write a [debugger visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts.aspx) for your type. Depending on your needs this might be overkill of course.

As @dtb has kindly noted in a comment, there is a visualizer provided out of the box which might be sufficent for your needs:

> There's a visualizer that shows text and honours line breaks. You can
>   access it from the magnifying glass icon in the tooltip. It's just the
>   tooltip that shows strings in C# string literal syntax

Comment: Well it might be, but since they aren't really asking for `ToString()` to behave any differently, but for the debugger to behave differently in terms of how it handles those strings, that's a good answer IMO.
It would be nice if the debugger offered a bit more flexibility here. If nothing else, there's a few cases on this site where the ability to switch how the debugger presents some things could have cleared up people's confusion fast.

Comment: in fact - that visualizer together with pining current variable works prety well! THNX!

Answer (score 1):

The debugger windows strip newlines from values.

If you want to see the newlines, print the value in the Immediate Window.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [DebuggerDisplay attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx), it offers more options.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [DebuggerDisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992.aspx), which gives you more control over what is displayed in the debugger. Not sure it allows multi-line text, though.